# SESSION and POST variables got mixed up

Tags: php, post, session-variables

On my localhost (Apache on Windows), $`_SESSION and $_POST` arrays are totally separate. When `$_POST['username']` is modified, `$_SESSION['username']` does not change.

However, when I run the same code on remote host, those two arrays seems to mix up. When `$_POST['username']` is modified, `$_SESSION['username']` also changes.

Why this problem arise? And how to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your `register_globals` in your PHP configuration file. I think it is set on `on`.

Be careful using `register_globals`, it is deprecated and has serious security risks.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php